# Laravel hasMany relation count number of likes and comments on post

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

The code:

```
$posts = Jumpsite::find($jid)
            ->posts()
            ->with('comments')
            ->with('likes')
            ->with('number_of_comments')
            ->with('number_of_likes')
            ->where('reply_to', 0)
            ->orderBy('pid', 'DESC')
            ->paginate(10);
```

Each post has a comment and likes. I only display a few of the comments initially to avoid large loads. But I want to show how many the total comments and likes for each post. How do I do this?

Model code:

```
public function likes()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Like', 'pid', 'pid');
}

public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Post', 'reply_to', 'pid')->with('likes')->take(4);
}

public function number_of_likes()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Like', 'pid', 'pid')->count();
}
```

Note:

```
This is an API. All will be returned as JSON.
```

---

**update**

The return

```
Post
    author_id
    message
    Comments(recent 4)
        user_id
        message
        post_date
        Number_of_likes
    Likes
        user_id
    Number_of_total_comments
    Number_of_total_likes
```

---

**update**

How I return the data

```
$posts  = $posts->toArray();
$posts  = $posts['data'];

return Response::json(array(
   'data' => $posts
));
```

Just by using that I get all the data i want in the json. But I also want to add the total counts.

---

**update**

```
protected $appends = array('total_likes');

public function getTotalLikesAttribute()
{
   return $this->hasMany('Like')->whereUserId($this->uid)->wherePostId($this->pid)->count();

}
```

but getting the error:

```
 Unknown column 'likes.post_id'
```

---

**error**

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'likes.post_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `likes` where `likes`.`deleted_at` is null and `likes`.`post_id` = 4 and `pid` = 4 and `uid` = 1)
```

Comment: Do you want to count for each post or when you need for a specific post?

Comment: @Anam I wanted to get the count for each post. This is like a feed. Lets say a facebook timeline.

Comment: what's different between author_id in Post and user_id in likes? are they same?

Comment: do you have column `post_id` in your `likes` table? Laravel don't find post_id in likes table.

Comment: @Anam no i dont. I have uid for user_id and pid for post_id on all tables. How do I tell laravel to find pid?

Comment: easy. change `wherePostId($this->pid)` to `where('pid', $this->pid)`. Similarly `whereUserId($this->uid)` to `where('uid', $this->uid)` .

Comment: @Anam i did. Please check my latest update. :) still same error though.

Comment: did you change this `return $this->hasMany('Like')->whereUserId($this->uid)->wherePostId($this->pid)->count();` ?

Comment: you could count the number of rows via the relationships defined in the model, **for details** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46546332/laravel-count-number-of-rows-in-a-relationship

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In your model place the following accessors:

**Count total Likes:**

```
 public function getTotalLikesAttribute()
 {
    return $this->hasMany('Like')->whereUserId($this->author_id)->count();

 }
```

**Count total comments:**

From your description, i can see, you have retrieving the number of posts as comments

```
public function getTotalCommentsAttribute()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Post')->whereUserId($this->author_id)->count();    
}
```

Now, from your controller:

```
$post  = Jumpsite::find($jid);

// total comments
var_dump( $post->total_comments );

// total Likes
var_dump( $post->total_likes );
```

Comment: Yes comments are just posts with a parent. This way I only have 1 table for posts and comments. if a post has a 0 parent then it is a post and not a comment. I will try this now.

Comment: Anyways, How do I display it into my json return? It still isn't getting added in the return. I updated my question. Also accessors aren't well documented in the laravel docs.

Comment: do see the counts if you dump variable?

Comment: Unknown column 'likes.post_id' in 'where clause'  should be likes.pid

Comment: Thanks. I finally got it to work. and great explanation on this.

Comment: This way you're loading a whole collection and only then count its elements in PHP. It's inefficient. For the correct answer see @sachin kumar's answer.

Answer (score 27):

You can use that following code for counting relation model result.

```
 $posts = App\Post::withCount('comments')->get(); foreach ($posts as $post) { echo $post->comments_count; }
```

And also set condition with count like this

```
$posts = Post::withCount(['votes', 'comments' => function ($query) { $query->where('content', 'like', 'foo%'); }])->get();
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. It avoids loading a whole collection in order to just get the number of its elements.

Comment: Thank you. @Mateusz

Answer (score 3):

Count comments for all blog posts in laravel

Step 1: Place this code inside your ‘Post’ model.

```
// Get the comments for the blog post.
public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
}
```

Step 2: Place this code inside your ‘PostController’ controller.

```
 $posts= Post::all();
 return view('home')->with('posts', $posts);
```

Step 3: Then count comments for all posts using the below code.

```
@foreach($posts as $row)
 {{$row->comments->count()}}
@endforeach
```

See details here: http://www.pranms.com/count-comments-for-all-blog-posts-in-laravel/

Answer (score 0):

Just  single change to get results of the count

In relation

```
 public function getTotalLikesAttribute(){
    return $this->hasMany('Like')->where('author_id',$this->author_id)->count();
}
```

In the view

```
$post->getTotalLikesAttribute()
```