# Laravel Eager Loading One to Many Relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eager-loading

Good day, I am having this problem where I am trying to retrieve the record from 2 tables

[image: eager loading]

```
class Leads extends Eloquent
{
    public function leademail()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('LeadDetailEmails'); 
    }
}

class LeadDetailEmails extends Eloquent
{
    public function lead()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Leads');
    }
}


class Category extends BaseController
{
    public function fetchRecord()
    {
        $result = Leads::with('leademail')->get();
    }
}
```

leadDetailEmails has foreign key set in the migration file

```
$table->foreign('lead_id')->references('id')->on('leads')->onDelete('cascade');
```

I am getting this error:

```
"message":"SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'lead_detail_emails.leads_model_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `lead_detail_emails` where `lead_detail_emails`.`leads_model_id` in (1, 2, 3))"
```

What can I do to fix the error? also, if there will be a third table(LeadDetailContact), how can I eager loading the table?

thanks.

Comment: You might get an idea [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20770284/laravel-hasmany-relation-count-number-of-likes-and-comments-on-post).

Comment: And where exactly you get this error.When using `fetchRecord` or in a piece of code you didn't show?

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek {"error":{"type":"Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException","message":"SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'lead_detail_emails.leads_model_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `lead_detail_emails` where `lead_detail_emails`.`leads_model_id` in (1, 2, 3))","file":"C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\xxxx\\crm\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Connection.php","line":625}} Yes on fetch record

Comment: The problem was laravel considers the foreign key of the lead_detail_email was leads_model_id, i overwrite it using 

return $this->hasMany('LeadDetailEmails','lead_id');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try specifying your table name for `LeadDetailEmails` in the following way:

```
class LeadDetailEmails extends Eloquent
{
    protected $table = 'leadDetailEmails';

    public function lead()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Leads');
    }
}
```

And if you have more relations you want to get with eager loading you can do it this way:

```
$result = Leads::with('leademail', 'leadcontact')->get();
```

Comment: I am still getting an error using this, I guess it is because of my naming convention, I am using 'Model' for my models. thanks though