# Laravel eager loading count relation

Tags: php, laravel, eager-loading

I have three models, Order, OrderProduct and Product. OrderProduct is the table that create the relation from Order and Product that stores information like price or quantity. In my product list action i need to show how many orders are open (pending or paid) for each product. So i'm trying to eager load this relation like this:

```
// ProductController.php

public function index()
{
    $data = Product::with(['reservedStock']);

    return $data;
}
```

And

```
//Product.php

public function reservedStock()
{
    return $this->hasMany(OrderProduct::class, 'product_sku')
        ->selectRaw('order_products.product_sku, count(*) as count')
        ->join('orders', 'orders.id', 'order_products.order_id')
        ->whereIn('orders.status', [Order::STATUS_PENDING, Order::STATUS_PAID]);
}
```

It works but the response from it is an array like this:

```
{
    "sku": 384,
    "brand_id": null,
    "line_id": null,
    "title": "Alcatel Pixi 4 Colors OT4034E 8GB 3G Preto",
    "ean": null,
    "ncm": 85171231,
    "price": "315.44",
    "cost": "0.00",
    "condition": 0,
    "warranty": null,
    "created_at": "2016-08-25 10:45:40",
    "updated_at": "2017-03-30 17:51:07",
    "deleted_at": null,
    "reserved_stock": [
        {
            "product_sku": 384,
            "count": 4
        }
    ]
}
```

I want only the count `reserved_stock: 4`.

Any ideas about how doing it?

ps: I've already tried doing `withCount` bit with it i'm not able to create the join from orders table to filter by order status.

Comment: Reading this will probably help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20770284/laravel-hasmany-relation-count-number-of-likes-and-comments-on-post

Comment: @Daan it's not eager loading. I want only one query for all my products. Following your reference, he created another attribute that is the count and then i call this on a foreach or something. I need to load this before showing.

Comment: You can only return count numbers. `return count($product->reservedStock);`?

Comment: Counting like that will not be enough in your purpose, it should sum(order_products.quantity) or something and you could reutrn that sum with query builder  sum() method

Comment: @DimitrisKontoulis i know, it's just an example purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something as follows, the relation might need some tinkering:

```
public function reservedStockCount()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(OrderProduct::class)
        ->selectRaw('order_products.id, count(*) as aggregate_reserved_stock')
        ->join('orders', 'orders.id', 'order_products.order_id')
        ->whereIn('orders.status', [Order::STATUS_PENDING, Order::STATUS_PAID]);
        ->groupBy('order_products.id');
}

public function getReservedStockCount()
{
    // if relation is not loaded already, let's do it first
    if (!array_key_exists('reservedStockCount', $this->relations)) {
        $this->load('reservedStockCount');
    }

    $related = $this->getRelation('reservedStockCount')->first();
    // then return the count directly
    return ($related) ? (int) $related->aggregate_reserved_stock : 0;
}
```

and can be used as follows:

```
Product::with(['reservedStockCount']);

Product->getReservedStockCount();
```

Comment: It worked! As i use laravel as an API i needed to create an custom attribute and appends it to my model using your method. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help!