# Get view, comment, like counts of an article using Laravel5.5 Eloquent Query Builder

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

I have three table i want to build a relationship with an SQL and have not been able to do that.
The concept is to get the number of views, comments and likes that was logged for an article. So I have the main

article table

> arm_articles

the article comment table

> arm_article_comments,

the article views table

> arm_article_views

the article likes table

> arm_article_likes

**MY ELOQUENT QUERY THAT DID NOT WORK**

```
DB::table('arm_articles')
    ->join('arm_article_views', function($join) {
        $join->on('arm_articles.article_id', '=', 'arm_article_views.view_article_id');
    })
    ->join('arm_article_likes', function($join) {
        $join->on('arm_articles.article_id', '=', 'arm_article_likes.liked_article_id');
    })
    ->join('arm_article_comments', function($join) {
        $join->on('arm_articles.article_id', '=', 'arm_article_comments.comment_article_id');
    })->groupBy('arm_articles.article_id')
    ->select('arm_articles.article_topic','arm_articles.article_id')
    ->addSelect(DB::raw('COUNT(arm_article_views.view_article_id) as TotalViews'))
    ->addSelect(DB::raw('COUNT(arm_article_likes.liked_article_id) as TotalLikes'))
    ->addSelect(DB::raw('COUNT(arm_article_comments.comment_article_id) as TotalComments'))
    ->where('arm_articles.article_contributor_id','=',$contributor_id)
    ->get()
```

This command dis not return any error but rather, it created a table that is not true. which i can not work with

---

**ARTICLE TABLE**
[arm_articles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOBTB.png)

KEY FIELDS

`arm_articles.id, arm_articles.article_id, arm_articles.article_contributor_id, arm_articles.article_active`

---

**ARTICLE VIEW TABLE**
[arm_article_views](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtqXp.png)

KEY FIELDS

`arm_article_views.view_article_id`
**JOIN WITH** arm_articles.article_id

---

**ARTICLE COMMENT TABLE**
[arm_article_comments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7NzKT.png)

KEY FIELD

`arm_article_comments.comment_article_id`
**JOIN WITH** arm_articles.article_id

---

**ARTICLE LIKE TABLE**
[arm_article_likes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3x3t0.png)

KEY FIELD

`arm_article_likes.liked_article_id` **JOIN WITH** arm_articles.article_id

---

I WANT TO FORM A NEW TABLE FROM MY SQL THAT WILL LOOK LIKE THIS
[new table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vONY.png)

Kindly assist with the right Command to form the new table with the right data, relating arm_articles table with arm_article_likes, arm_article_views and arm_article_comments.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You can build relationships that are counts for relationships. You can see how you would accomplish this here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43873577/1561929.

Comment: The link u sent to me is completely different from this one..
What i need is an SQL to get the count of views, likes and comment of each article